# Proper Criteria for Shiro plugin in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm, criteria, shiro

I have Shiro domain classes as below:

```
class ShiroUser {
String email
String password

static hasMany = [ roles: ShiroRole, permissions: String ]

static constraints = {
    email(nullable: false, blank: false, unique: true)
    }
}


class ShiroRole {
String name

static hasMany = [ users: ShiroUser, permissions: String ]
static belongsTo = ShiroUser

static constraints = {
    name(nullable: false, blank: false, unique: true)
     }
}
```

I received ShiroUser's email from params.email. And I want to find out the permission that  belongsTo ShiroUser using criteria().

I tried the below code, but couldn't succeed.

```
 def criteria= permissions.createCriteria().listDistinct {
                ShiroRole{
                     ShiroUser{
                         eq("email", params.email)
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your criteria is wrongly built. I'd keep it simple and put like:

```
def permissions = ShiroUser.findByEmail( params.email )?.roles*.permissions.flatten() as Set
```

If you want to stick with criteria:

```
def permissions = ShiroRole.createCriteria().listDistinct {
                    projections{ 
                       property 'permissions'
                    }
                    users{
                         eq "email", params.email
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. Only you just missed an opening parenthesis before "email" in criteria.

Comment: No, I did not. It's groovy

Comment: I was referring this  (http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html) to create Criteria. There parenthesis was used  in eq.

Comment: parenthesis are optional in groovy and left in the docs only for java programmers. btw I remove the closing one, now it's fine